# Unmap all combinations starting with certain key

Tags: key-bindings

I am experimenting with default key mappings and am considering remapping the `g` key entirely. But first I would like to turn off all the existing mappings that `g` has. For now I am using this kind of hack:

```
" disable all g maps
let g:netrw_nogx = 1 " allows disabling gx
let s:chars1 = map(range(char2nr('a'), char2nr('x')), 'nr2char(v:val)')
let s:chars2 = map(range(char2nr('A'), char2nr('Z')), 'nr2char(v:val)')
let s:chars = s:chars1 + s:chars2
let s:chars = s:chars+['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','-','=','_']
let s:chars = s:chars+['~','`','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','/','?']
let s:chars = s:chars+['[',']','{','}','\','\|',':',';','"',"'",'<',">",'.',',']

for char in s:chars
  execute 'noremap g' . char . ' <nop>'
endfor
```

But this is very messy and `g<ctrl-_>` maps are still left in.

Is there some cleaner way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think there is no better way other than to iterate over all combinations.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you need to remap all of these combinations to `<nop>`? Also, I agree with Christian that is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Agree with @statox why not use unmap?

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble I think what Karolis wants to do is to disable the built-in normal mode commands like `gq`, `gU`, etc while `unmap` would be useful to delete mappings created by the user. What I was wondering is, why does one need to disable all of these built-in commands?

Comment: @statox I am just experimenting with making (neo)vim maps more intuitive. For example my current experiment is to only use `g` prefix for "goto" commands. I.E. `gg` goes to top `G` goes to bottom, `gf` goes to file, `gb` and `gB` would traverse buffers, etc. No big reason to disable all g prefix maps, but it would help in a sense that I would be sure pressing `g` will put me into a `goto` context and would not do something else by accident.

Comment: I see. In my opinion, it is more efficient to get used to the built-in commands since you will be able to use them everywhere but if you really want to disable them your solution is probably the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Suppressing the built-in `g`

Here's a mapping that will suppress all `g`-prefixed bindings, and only allow custom mappings that begin with `g`.

```
function! SuppressG()
  let c = nr2char(getchar())
  if maparg('g'.c, 'n') != ''
    return 'g'.c
  else
    return '\<Nop>'
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> g SuppressG()
```

The idea is to make a top-level mapping for `g` itself that then reads a single character from the keyboard. If a Normal mode mapping to `g` followed by the input character exists, return that. Otherwise, return `<Nop>`. It works with chords, too.

The effect is that when you haven't defined any other mappings beginning with `g`, all of Vim's built-in bindings beginning with `g` will do nothing. For example, `ge`, which normally moves backwards to the end of a word, would now be a no-op.

#### Creating a custom mapping

If you also defined a custom mapping to `ge`, then your mapping would take effect. Example:

```
nnoremap ge G
```

Now `ge` moves to the last line of the buffer, but all other `g` bindings still do nothing.

#### Restoring built-ins

You can also restore the `g` mappings you want to keep. For example:

```
nnoremap gg gg
```

This makes `gg` once again move to the first line of the buffer.

Comment: This works really well for "g" and "z" but for some reason I cannot figure out how to make it work for "ctrl". Maybe you have any tips?

Comment: Ctrl itself isn't mappable, it's just part of a chord. Vim sees things like Ctrl+x as a single character.

Comment: Does it gets called immediately? Not waiting for any longer combination that could surpass it?

Answer (score 2):

If your version of vim is recent enough, you could obtain all the mappings starting with `g` thanks to `getcompletion('g', 'mapping')`.

However, you won't know the mode associated, you'd need to filter the list with `mapcheck()`.

Of course, you won't obtain the default keybindings this way.

Comment: Presumably you'd need to do this in a `VimEnter` autocommand (to `unmap` mappings added by plugins)?

Answer (score 2):

A small generalization to tommcdo's excellent suggestion:

```
function! SuppressAllStartingWith(c1)
  let c2 = nr2char(getchar())
  if maparg(a:c1.c2, 'n') != ''
    return a:c1.c2
  else
    return '\<Nop>'
  endif
endfunction
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
nnoremap <expr> q SuppressAllStartingWith('q')
nnoremap <expr> z SuppressAllStartingWith('z')
```

As for motivation, in command mode I'm always fat-fingering 'z' when I'm heading for 'x', or 'q' when I'm heading for 'a', and I'm tired of that.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Does this prevent you from recording macros `q{letter}` or using the fold and other `z` commands (`zt`, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, it does.  For certain of my editing jobs, I don't want any accidental keystrokes moving the cursor far away, or changing modes, or turning on anything.  I just want local motions and text insert/delete, basically.  This gets me partially there.  If there's a WYSIWYG mode to vim, or a better way to achieve this, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Vim is WYSIWYG if what you get is plain-text, so I don't follow that. But you could look at `:help -y`.

Comment: I was using WYSIWG in the sense of what the nano editor gives you, i.e., exactly what -y gives you in vim, thanks for that tip.  But what I'd like to achieve in vim is allowing editing commands that operate on the current line, or a few lines around it, and suppressing commands that take me to other parts of the file when I mistype them.  So for example I never use z because I have no use for what it does, and when I accidentally hit it, I don't want what it does.