# unbind all keybindings starting with [ and ]

Tags: key-bindings

I put this:

```
noremap [ {
noremap ] }
```

in my `.vimrc`. However, since there are other keybindings starting with `[` and `]`, vim waits for the next keybinding before executing my desired command.

After reviewing [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15370/unmap-all-combinations-starting-with-certain-key) article, I attempted to apply the solution for  `[` and `]`, but failed. The code was written for the `g` prefix, and I was unsuccessful in modifying it for `[` and `]`.

How can I remove all keybindings starting with `[` and `]` in vim so I can avoid the delay when using my own bindings for `[` and `]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to achieve this is to make a buffer-local nowait mapping.

```
autocmd FileType * nnoremap <nowait><buffer> [ {
autocmd FileType * nnoremap <nowait><buffer> ] }
```

Another option is to use `langmap`:

```
set langmap=[{,]}
```

You can use the associated option `langremap` to adjust whether `[` and `]` inside mappings will have the usual or new actions.